# Java, model для БД, уникальные значение

Tags: java, spring-boot

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Staff {

    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) 

    private Long personnelNumber;
    private String fname, lname, pname, position;

    public Staff(Long personnelNumber, String fname, String lname, String pname, String position) {
        this.personnelNumber = personnelNumber;
        this.fname = fname;
        this.lname = lname;
        this.pname = pname;
        this.position = position;
    }
    public Staff() {

    }
    public Long getPersonnelNumber() {
        return personnelNumber;
    }
    public void setPersonnelNumber(Long personnelNumber) {
        this.personnelNumber = personnelNumber;
    }
    public String getFname() {
        return fname;
    }
    public void setFname(String fname) {
        this.fname = fname;
    }
    public String getLname() {
        return lname;
    }
    public void setLname(String lname) {
        this.lname = lname;
    }
    public String getPname() {
        return pname;
    }
    public void setPname(String pname) {
        this.pname = pname;
    }
    public String getPosition() {
        return position;
    }
    public void setPosition(String position) {
        this.position = position;
    }
}
```

Есть модель для БД, что нужно написать в Стратегии, чтобы Табельный номер был уникальный и нельзя было написать такой же номер при заполнении БД в браузере. Или для этого нужно в другом месте прописывать какую-то уникальность?

Answer (score 1):

Можно ограничить уникальным индексом

```
@Table(indexes = {@Index(columnList="personnelNumber", unique = true)})
```

Можно везде проверок добавить, не существует ли запись.